# Windows Server: Is it possible to run Certificate Authority while having Essentials experience installed?

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate-authority, essentials-2012, media

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine running a certification authority, but also need the same server to run Windows Server Essentials Media Pack. This requires the Essentials Experience role to be installed, which cannot be installed when CA is.

So what I'm wondering before I reinstall the CA is whether or not I'd be able to install CA after installing Essentials Experience. According this [page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551157.aspx) Essentials Experience allows "... the customer can take advantage of all the features that are available in Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials without the locks and limits".

But I really don't want to uninstall the CA and try this in case I have to reissue all my certificates for no reason. I could solve this by moving the CA to a virtual machine, but resources are spares on the server, so I'd rather not.

Does anyone know if this would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to answer this is to try it in a VM. I

- installed a new OS
- added the `Windows Server Essentials Experience`
- added the `Active Directory Certificate Services` and all dependencies
- Used the `AD CS Configuration` wizard to configure a root Standalone CA

This all worked fine on a 2012 R2 Standard OS, I don't have any 2012 images for testing anymore.

If you are using 2012 Essentials, then the essentials role is installed already anyway

Comment: Hey, i've now uninstalled the CA and now i get a different error message. Seems to be related to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2914651 . The message im getting it the one described there. I've followed the steps there, but it doesn't seem to help. I'm only able to add the ServerAdmin$ user and not the MediaAdmin$ user, as i don't think it exists. Do you have any tips for this?

Comment: Created a user MediaAdmin$ but this didn't help either. Aslo don't see any errors in the log.

Comment: Solved this by starting over completely. :\